# Cloud Function Script writes on all uid's

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have an issue where my Cloud Function script detects a write change from a specific user in the Firestore database.
The idea is that on triggered write change i calculate a new total value for that user, ie when a new walking distance is written from local user i calculate a new total distance on cloud functions. Unfortunately it seems as my script detects the change correct but then writes the new values for ALL uid/documents in the database. I only want to update the fields of the user that the change was detected for. What am I doing wrong here?
I checked that the uid value is the actual user id that the change was registered on, cause i checked in console log after debugging.

```
module.exports.LogSummary = functions.firestore
.document('Logs/{userId}').onWrite((change, context) => {
  const uid = context.params.userId;

  let TotalDistance = 0;
  TotalDistance = 
    change.after.data().Running_Distance + 
    change.after.data().Walking_Distance;

  return db
    .collection('Logs')
    .doc(uid)
    .update({
      Total_Distance_Cloud: TotalDistance})
    .catch(console.error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_for_any_change_to_a_document
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#writing_data

> If you don't care about the type of event being fired, you can listen for all changes in a Cloud Firestore document using the onWrite() function with a wildcard This example function calls modifyUser if a user is created, updated, or deleted:
>
> Each function invocation is associated with a specific document in your Cloud Firestore database. You can access that document as a DocumentReference in the ref property of the snapshot returned to your function.

Caution!!!

> Note: Any time you write to the same document that triggered a function, you are at risk of creating an infinite loop. Use caution and ensure that you safely exit the function when no change is needed.

If an infinite loops occurred then you should delete the cloud function on google cloud console.

Check to not infinite loops and try the following code.

```
module.exports.LogSummary = functions.firestore
  .document("Logs/{userId}")
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
    // If the document does not exist, it has been deleted.
    if (!change.after.exists) {
      return;
    }
    // Retrieve the current value
    const data = change.after.data();
    const totalDistance = data.Running_Distance + data.Walking_Distance;

    // This is crucial to prevent infinite loops.
    if (data.Total_Distance_Cloud === totalDistance) {
      return;
    }

    // Then return a promise of a set operation to update
    return change.after.ref.update({
      Total_Distance_Cloud: totalDistance
    });
  });
```